# CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'byte' C#

Tags: c#

```
private byte[] ParsePatternString(string szPattern)
{
  List<byte> list = new List<byte>();
  foreach ( string text in szPattern.Split(new char[] { ' ' }) )
  {
    list.Add((text == "?") ? 0 : Convert.ToByte(text, 16));
  }
  return list.ToArray();
}
```

The error happens on `list.Add((text == "?") ? 0 : Convert.ToByte(text, 16));`
What I am wondering is how what is creating the error, because based on the other questions about a similar issue I tried and it seems to not have worked.

Comment: Beginning with C# 9.0, conditional expressions are target-typed. So in C# 9, your code will work. Don't sit on the old version, switch to the new one.

Answer (score 3):

`0` is an `int` literal. Just like C, there's no way to specify an [integer literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#integer-literals) smaller than `int`. The [type of a conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) is the common type of the two values, thus your expression results in an `int` expression and can't be passed to a `byte` argument. You need to cast the expression to `byte` using either of the following

```
list.Add(text == "?" ? (byte)0 : Convert.ToByte(text, 16));
list.Add((byte)(text == "?" ? 0 : Convert.ToByte(text, 16)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `byte.MinValue` in this case:

```
private byte[] ParsePatternString(string szPattern)
{
    List<byte> list = new List<byte>();
    foreach ( string text in szPattern.Split(new char[] { ' ' }) )
    {
        list.Add(text == "?" ? byte.MinValue : Convert.ToByte(text, 16));
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have actually never used CSharp before but I think the problem might be that it reads 0 as an int and not a Boolean, and doesn't automatically convert it. From what I'm reading about it you need to add an explicit cast like this:

```cs
list.Add((text == "?") ? (byte) 0 : Convert.ToByte(text, 16));
```